# Temporal analysis in GIS - Tool to identify the jump points

Tags: software-recommendations, analysis, time

I'm searching for a tool that help to analysis spatial temporal data in GIS.

This is my problem:

I have a database with a set of 170 georeferenced ovitraps (traps to catch mosquitoes eggs) with the eggs values collected byweek.
  
The values of the eggs collected in each ovitrap, vary widely from one week to the next, according to the time of year. But these changes are not equal in all ovitraps, because they have different locations and so they are locate in different microclimates.

My aim is to identify in each week which are ovitraps that have the highest jump values.

To better understand how are my data, I leave down a image.

[image]

The rows are the ovitraps and the columns are the weeks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you mean by "jump values"?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that enables visual analysis or do you just need code/instructions that spits out the ovitrap IDs with the biggest changes per week?

Comment: Jump Values - values that changed more from one week to the other

Comment: Underdark i am looking for the two thinks.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use Excel.

You would open the .dbf file in a spreadsheet.
To compare two columns to find the maximum difference and return the row I found this forum post: 
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174135

The conclusion they reached is to that the following should return the row where the maximum difference between two columns is found:

{=INDEX(C1:C8,MATCH(MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A8)*ISNUMBER(B1:B8),ABS(A1:A8-B1:B8),"")),ABS(A1:A8-B1:B8),0))}

NB it is an array formula, so omit the curly braces and press 'ctrl+shift+enter' instead of just 'enter'

In this case columns A and B are one data set and column C is the index - in your case the number of the ovitrap.